# How to sort data including str and number the "normal" way [Python]

Tags: python

I have a data frame with a "str+number" column. For example,

```
            Col.1
row.1.  "txt 0.001 no"
row.2.  "txt 0.003no"
row.3.  "txt 5 yes"
row.4.  "txt 0.0001no"
row.5.  "txt 100yes"
row.6.  "txt 1 no"
```

but currently it sort as

```
        Col.1
row.3.  "txt 0.0001no"
row.1.  "txt 0.001 no"
row.2.  "txt 0.003no"
row.4.  "txt 100yes"
row.5.  "txt 1 no"
row.6.  "txt 5 yes"
```

I want it to sort as:

```
        Col.1
row.3.  "txt 0.0001no"
row.1.  "txt 0.001 no"
row.2.  "txt 0.003no"
row.5.  "txt 1 no"
row.6.  "txt 5 yes"
row.4.  "txt 100yes"
```

I know it has something to do with how python is normally sort, like `100 > 5` because of the one, but now I have the str in front of the number, so i can't use `int()`. what should i do?

Comment: Have a look at the natsort module (its not in the standard library

Comment: @Programmer problem solved, feel free to make this into official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too encountered this behaviour - see [here](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/howitworks.html#first-how-does-natural-sorting-work-at-a-high-level) for an explanation. The solution was to use [`natsort.natsorted(iterable)`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#natsort.natsorted) (to be used like the builtin `sorted(...)` function):

```py
>>> import natsort
>>> natsort.natsorted(["0.001", "0.01", "0.1", "1", "5", "100"])
['0.001', '0.01', '0.1', '1', '5', '100']
```

Please note that the `natsort` is not contained in the standard library; that means that yu will have to install it either using your OS's package manager, `pip` or install it manually. It offers many other useful functions, by the way.

Comment: but wondering why is `natsorted(['txt 0.001', 'txt 0.1', 'txt 0.005'])` not work?

Comment: @MathAvengers idk, but using `natsorted.realsorted` instead pf `natsort.natsorted` works as expected

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to sort with those numbers that you've in Col.1. You can extract those numbers and then try to sort them -

```
df['Value'] = df['Col1'].str.extract(pat = r"(\d{1,}\.{0,}\d{0,})")
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'])
```

If you now do a sort on 'Value' Column it'll work.